# Increasing size of an array dynamically

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I would like to increase the size of an array in a for loop. Currently I am doing it manually:

```
m_array varchar array default array[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

I would like to increase it by checking the length of a column (`select count(*) from ...`) and set this value as the size of the array. Or is there another way to solve this problem in PostgreSQL?

EDIT
The values in the array should be 0s in the beginning, it gets filled in another loop and after the loop the array values are set back to 0s.

EDIT II

`array_fill(0,'{28}')` works for me. Is there also an way to replace the {28} by a variable which will be defined after the declaration. **Use Case:** I am using the array in a mapping function. Every array element represents a product and in the end with `array_to_string` I get an one-dimensional binary-code.

EDIT III

`array_fill(0,array[variable])` worked for me! Thank you guys!

Comment: Just append new elements. There is no need to manually increase the size.  You don't even need to initialize with a specific size. `m_array varchar[] default array[];` would be enough (although in general `text` should be preferred over `varchar`)

Comment: the values in the array should be 0s in the beginning, it gets filled in another loop and after the loop the array values are set back to 0s

Comment: Nevertheless there is no special operation to "resize" an array - just append new values

Comment: `Or is there another way to solve this problem in postgresql?` Pretty sure there is. Not so sure what "the problem" is exactly. Please clarify the use case, and start by declaring your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You do not need to "resize" the array (I'm also not aware of such function). If you need new values in the beginning or in the end of your array, just append them using `||`:

```
SELECT 
  array[0]||array[1,2,3],  
  array[1,2,3]||array[0];

 ?column?  | ?column?  
-----------+-----------
 {0,1,2,3} | {1,2,3,0}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need actual `0` values at predefined array positions, consider **`array_fill()`**.
[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> Returns an array filled with copies of the given value, having
> dimensions of the lengths specified by the second argument. The
> optional third argument supplies lower-bound values for each dimension
> (which default to all `1`).

```sql
test=> SELECT array_fill(0, '{28}');
                        array_fill                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
(1 row)
```

(But I suspect misunderstandings around the workings of arrays and/or when and how to best use them.)